# Sum data for many different results for same field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to find a better way to write this sql server code 2008. It works and data is accurate. Reason i ask is that i will be asked to do this for several other reports going forward and want to reduce the amount of code to upkeep going forward.
How can i take a field where i sum for the yes/no/- (dash) in each field without doing an individual sum as i have in code. Each table is a month of detail data which i sum using in a CTE. i changed the table name for each month and Union All to put data together. Is there a better way to do this. This is a small sample of code. Thanks for the help.

```
WITH H AS (
SELECT 'August' AS Month_Name
    , SUM(CASE WHEN G.FFS = '-'     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FFS_Dash
    , SUM(CASE WHEN G.FFS = 'Yes'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FFS_Yes
    , SUM(CASE WHEN G.FFS = 'No'    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FFS_No
    , SUM(CASE WHEN G.DNA = '-'     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DNA_Dash
    , SUM(CASE WHEN G.DNA = 'Yes'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DNA_Yes
    , SUM(CASE WHEN G.DNA = 'No'    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DNA_No
FROM table08 G )
, G AS (
SELECT 'July' AS Month_Name
    , SUM(CASE WHEN G.FFS = '-'     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FFS_Dash
    , SUM(CASE WHEN G.FFS = 'Yes'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FFS_Yes
    , SUM(CASE WHEN G.FFS = 'No'    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FFS_No
    , SUM(CASE WHEN G.DNA = '-'     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DNA_Dash
    , SUM(CASE WHEN G.DNA = 'Yes'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DNA_Yes
    , SUM(CASE WHEN G.DNA = 'No'    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DNA_No
FROM table07 G )
select * from H 
UNION ALL
select * from G
```

Comment: Don't forget about utilizing views, which make a very handy way of hiding/encapsulating operations.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
SELECT Month_Name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN G.FFS = '-'     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FFS_Dash,
       SUM(CASE WHEN G.FFS = 'Yes'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FFS_Yes,
       SUM(CASE WHEN G.FFS = 'No'    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FFS_No,
       SUM(CASE WHEN G.DNA = '-'     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DNA_Dash,
       SUM(CASE WHEN G.DNA = 'Yes'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DNA_Yes,
       SUM(CASE WHEN G.DNA = 'No'    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DNA_No
FROM ((select 'July' as Month_Name, G.*
       from table07 G
      ) union all
      (select 'August', H.*
       from table08 H
      )
     ) gh
GROUP BY Month_Name;
```

However, having tables with the same structure is usually a sign of poor database design.  You should have a single table with a column representing the month.

Comment: The tables i am using are a saved version of a report so we dont have to run this report every time. It takes sevral hours to run the query that generates the report. My code is to sum at high level what the details of the report are doing month to month. Report is rather large and contains around 180 columns in excel. Plus new fields do get added and subtracted depending on business needs, wants etc...

Comment: Thanks Gordon. i have added the other tables using your code and it works.

Comment: @user3933707 . . . I would suggest that you create a view over the data.  Such a view is called a `partitioned view` in this case.  You'll find the example in the documentation illustrative:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190019(v=sql.105).aspx.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am a BA/QA person on project and do not have rights to do that sort of thing.